# CPU vs GPU usage in Keras (Tensorflow 2.1)

Tags: python, keras, gpu, cpu, tensorflow2.0

I have successfully set up `TensorFlow 2.1.0` with access to my GPU:

[image]

If I use Keras (`from tensorflow import keras`) to fit some `Sequential` model (like in example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)), will by default be used GPU or CPU for that? Is there some command to see which one is in use by Keras and can I somehow set this up myself? I would really like to see some very basic Keras model trained on GPU vs CPU to have a better feeling about the difference in performance.

Comment: See the with tf.device examples here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

Comment: Yes I saw that but I was looking for some Keras example too. I was not sure if I should already use `with tf.device` for model definition and calling compile or only for the fitting command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TensorFlow 2.1, GPU and CPU packages are together in the same package, `tensorflow`, not like in previous versions which had separate versions for CPU and GPU : `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`.

You can test to have a better feeling in this way:

```
   #Use only CPU
   import os 
   os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Or you can make your video card visible to TensorFlow by either allowing the default configurations just like above, or to force it via:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
```

Note that in the above setting, if you had 4 GPUs for example, you would set:

```
 os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1,2,3'
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! And without setting this up, how can I tell which one was used by default?

Comment: By default, TensorFlow tries to use the GPU, and if it is not found, it falls back to CPU. So if tf.config.experimental sees your GPU as it does in your example, you will use the GPU for training instead of CPU.

Comment: In addition to this, you may want to install a third-party software to monitor your GPU usage. If you train on Windows, GPU-Z is a good tool for monitoring. If you train on Linux, you can use nvidia-smi to be sure your network is training on GPU.

Comment: I usually wait few hours to encourage more users to give some inputs. :)

BTW I tested it and it works. What is interesting is that the example I was referring to in my questions runs faster on CPU (i7-9750H) then on GPU (Nvidia's GTX 1650).

Comment: If the neural network is extremely small, it may be the case that it runs faster on your CPU than GPU, since the benefits of parallel computations are outweighed by the overhead of transferring between the CPU and GPU